# How to scrape data from a login required website

Tags: r

I am trying to access to some websites which require login info. For example the

```
url = "http://www.myvisajobs.com/H1B-Visa/LCA.aspx?ID=1839728&NO=I-200-13042-600507&ST=Certified"
```

Without login, some info is hidden. For example,

```
 Address: login to view
```

If I log into it, those info shows up.

```
Address: 200 WEST STREET
```

My question is that how to get the complete info from that website with my user/password info? Especially, there is `@` in my user name, say, `abc@gmail.com`. I learned some tricks online (see below). However, with `@` in the userid part, it seems not to work. Your advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
zz <- url("http://userid:passw@domain.name:port/...")
readLines(zz)
```

Comment: depending on the site security, you may have to emulate a browser. R may not be the best for that but you can consider the package RSelenium: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-saucelabs.html